# How to fake a fireball?

Tags: combustion

It is for my book: i need some material, what would burn very bright for a long time, what could it be? Or another advises, how could a character fake a fireball, seen in the sky for a long time?

Answer (score 3):

Catch a bunch of fireflies and fill a transparent balloon with them and a mixture of helium and oxygen.

Comment: Innovative, I like it.